# Update Account (PUT) Endpoint in new Yodlee API for MFA

Tags: yodlee

**Background**

I am using the newer Yodlee Aggregation API that differs from what I was previously building off of.

I am currently using this endpoint in the account registration flow to put the MFA response:

`PUT /{cobrandName}/v1/providers/{providerAccountId}`

My request looks like this:

```
{
  url: `${this.rest}providers/${providerAccountId}`,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `cobSession=${self.appToken}, userSession=${token}`
  },
  form: {
    'MFAChallenge': JSON.stringify(newMfa)
  }
}
```

where `this.rest` is my personal rest url, `providerAccountId` is the appropriate providerAccountId for the refresh, `self.appToken` is the current cobrand session token, `token` is the current user's login token, and `newMfa` is a JSON object being stringified that matches this profile:

```
{
"loginForm": {
    "mfaTimeout": 94650,
    "formType": "questionAndAnswer",
    "row": [
    {
        "id": "SQandA--QUESTION_1--Row--1",
        "fieldRowChoice": "0001",
        "form": "0001",
        "label": "What is the name of your state?",
        "field": [
            {
                "id": "SQandA_QUESTION_1_1",
                "name": "QUESTION_1",
                "isOptional": false,
                "value": "Enter the answer",
                "valueEditable": true,
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "SQandA--QUESTION_2--Row--2",
        "fieldRowChoice": "0001",
        "form": "0001",
        "label": "What is the name of your first school",
        "field": [
            {
                "id": "SQandA_QUESTION_2_2",
                "name": "QUESTION_2",
                "isOptional": false,
                "value": "Enter the answer",
                "valueEditable": true,
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

with the exeption being the `value` fields of the `field` object, which have been encrypted with PKI as per instructions.

**Issue**

However, when I carry out this `PUT` request, I get this error from Yodlee:

```
{ errorCode: 'Y803',
errorMessage: 'MFAChallenge or providerParam required',
referenceCode: 'p1460412835654A4Q24t' }
```

though I clearly have an MFAChallenge parameter in my form. Any ideas on why I could be getting this error if the MFAChallenge is present (and note that it is the only info that is passed through the PUT request other than through headers or url parameters)? I tried putting it through as `body` data, but that doesn't seem to work, and very few of the API endpoints actually seem to use `body` over form encoded strings, though there was at least one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send this information MFAChallenge as part of URL, see below example

> https://developer.api.yodlee.com/ysl/restserver/v1/providers**/10114184?MFAChallenge=**%7B%20%22loginForm%22%3A%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22mfaTimeout%22%3A%2094650%2C%20%20%20%20%20%22formType%22%3A%20%22questionAndAnswer%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%22row%22%3A%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22SQandA--QUESTION_1--Row--1%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22fieldRowChoice%22%3A%20%220001%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22form%22%3A%20%220001%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22What%20is%20the%20name%20of%20your%20state%3F%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22field%22%3A%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22SQandA_QUESTION_1_1%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22QUESTION_1%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22isOptional%22%3A%20false%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22value%22%3A%20%22Enter%20the%20answer%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22valueEditable%22%3A%20true%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22text%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22SQandA--QUESTION_2--Row--2%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22fieldRowChoice%22%3A%20%220001%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22form%22%3A%20%220001%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22label%22%3A%20%22What%20is%20the%20name%20of%20your%20first%20school%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22field%22%3A%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22SQandA_QUESTION_2_2%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22QUESTION_2%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22isOptional%22%3A%20false%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22value%22%3A%20%22Enter%20the%20answer%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22valueEditable%22%3A%20true%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22text%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%5D%20%7D